# Could Goku actually be an earth "Prince"?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

Ok so in the Dragon Ball/DBZ/DBGT/DB Super universe, everyone knows that Goku and Chi Chi are married and that Chi Chi is the daughter of the Ox King. That technically makes Chi Chi the Ox princess. But am I crazy or wouldn't that technically mean that by marrying the Ox princess Chi Chi, that Goku is unofficially the "Ox Prince"? And what do you think Vegeta would do if he realized that Goku was also technically a saiyan "prince" (quote unquote)?

Answer (score 2):

Well, Goku may be the Ox Prince but I don't remember being ever stated how big that kingdom is, or how wealthy. 
As for Vegeta, he's a real prince, but of a now destroyed planet.